# How can Critical Chain scheduling be undertaken with Microsoft Project 2010?

Tags: ms-project, planning, scheduling, ms-project-2010

How can Critical Chain as a scheduling approach be applied using only Microsoft Project 2010 with no add-ins or additional software? What settings and options need to be used, and what task types.

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! Are you referring to [Critical chain project management developed by Eliyahu M. Goldratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_chain_project_management)?

Comment: Yes thats the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, Project does not use critical chain methodology - only critical path.  There are add ins (ProChain for example) but not native to the product.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Is there any suggested customisations, VBA or work arounds though? A third party add-in is not an option for my organisation.

Comment: If you use your favorite search engine and search for Agile in Microsoft Project, you'll see a variety of resources ranging from YouTube videos.  Here's a link to the MS project webcasts.  Take a look at Tim Runcie's webcast from Dec 2013. http://blogs.office.com/2013/08/12/microsoft-project-webcast-series/

Comment: its a pain to register too but the webcast was helpful, thankyou

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad you found it helpful.